# MPS Generator - is it possible to reference an external language's label?

Tags: mps

For example, I have language generators:

```
1) A -> baseLanguage
    a) defines a concept `a1`
    b) defines a label `a1ToClass`, in: `a1` of `A`, out: `ClassConcept` of `baseLanguage`
2) B -> A
    a) defines a concept `b1`
    b) defines a label `b1ToA1`, in: `b1` of `B`, out: `a1` of `A`
```

Is it possible to reference label `a1ToClass` from the latter generator in the following form?

```
node<b1> b1Instance = getB1InstanceNode(); 
node<a1> a1Instance = genContext.get output by label "b1ToA1" and input `b1Instance`;
node<ClassConcept> classConceptInstance = genContext.get output by label "a1ToClass" and input `a1Instance`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

you need a "Design" dependency from the B generator on A generator. Then the mapping label becomes visible.

Vaclav